# Start/Stop DispatcherTimer from a different thread

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

Here is my code..

```
public DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();

void somefunction (parameters){

if (something)
  tmr.Start();
if (something else)
  tmr.Stop();

   }
```

My problem is that I can't access the Start/Stop methods of the tmr object from the second function since it runs on a different thread!!!

Can somebody please help me?? I am struck wih this problem for almost 3 days! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Invoke it via Dispatcher (for marshaling the call from another thread) like so

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>timer.Start())
```

Comment: thanks hasan..but since "tmr" is already a DispatcherTimer object, it does not have a Dispatcher method in it! This would have worked if tmr is just a timer object, but it is not.. :(

Comment: it still does not work. The error I get is.. System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Gowtham Try begininvoke instead

Comment: I tried setting Isenabled to true or false. but that doesnt work either. Can you please tell me how to use BeginInvoke ?? I really appreciate the interest you are taking in this....:)

Comment: sorry...that was my bad. Thanks a lot !!! It worked!!!! Can you post your source..for further reference!

Comment: +1 However there is no need to cast a lambda of () to `Action` in fact since the timer.Start has the same signature as `Action` there isn't any need for a lambda at all.  This will work: `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(timer.Start);`

Comment: @AnthonyWJones you're right. Didn't notice it was taking Action. In WPF it is just a Delegate I think (for which casting is required).